# Can't add view as html page (sails.js)

Tags: html, node.js, sails.js

Good day.

I create a new sails.js project, create new controller (FooController), create model (Foo), in configuration file as view engine setted 'ejs', i create action that show list of Foo, in index.ejs view, add route for this view, but i cannot add details.html for detail view, in routes.js, error 'Ignore attempt to bind route ...', sails.js doesn't understand html file.

```
'/': {
    view: 'home/index'
},

'/foo': {
    view: 'foo/index'
},

'/fooDetails': {
    view: 'foo/details.html'
}
```

Please explain how to add html page to application as view? Or it is impossible?

And give some link where i can get some experiense about sails.js and sails.js features.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

To serve an html page from the assets folder directly you can do this in `config/routes.js`:

```
'/fooDetails': function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile(sails.config.appPath + '/assets/foo/details.html');
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the `sails.config.appPath` for it to work for me

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to directly pass a file with .html extension  , why not just

```
'/fooDetails': {
    view: 'foo/details'
}
```

And then paste all your html in details.ejs ?

Comment: May be you give me some code example? i'm noob in sails and ejs, i try to call from html page ajax request for 'Foo' details and past it to form controls, can you write example how i can do it? In ejs code i can't do it, sails throw error in code where i use ajax request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i figure out the example of youtube.com, how work controller and view. [Here example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XWIk9tb09Q).